# Javascript code doesn't work in ios and Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have javascript code that seems to work in all browsers and platforms, but it doesn't work in ios and Safari, I've tried to enable JS in preferences, it didn't help. Here is html part of code:

```js
var images = [];

      (function() {
        generateCards()
      })();

      var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

      Array.from(cards).forEach(function(card) {
        card.addEventListener('click', function() {
          Array.from(card.querySelectorAll('.back, .front')).forEach(function(el) {
            ['back', 'front'].forEach(function(s) {
              el.classList.toggle(s)
            });
          });
        });
      });

      //Displaying different images on click
      function cardImg(index) {
        var cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,10);
        if (images[index] !== undefined) 
        {
          images[index] = -1;
        }
          
        while (images.indexOf(cardNewImg)!= -1){
          cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,11); 
        }  
        images[index] = cardNewImg;
      }

      function generateCards() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          cardImg(i);
        }
      }

      function getCard(index) {
        if(!images[index].valid) {
          cardImg(index)
        }
        document["randimg"+(index + 1)].src = "https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/" + images[index]+".jpg";
      }

      function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
      {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
      }
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
 display: none;
}

.wrap {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #A770EF;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FDB99B, #CF8BF3, #A770EF);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FDB99B, #CF8BF3, #A770EF); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.card {
 width: 200px;
 height: 345px;
 position: relative;
 perspective: 1000px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

.front, .back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: 1s;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.front {
 transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.back  {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.img1 {
 width: 200px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 height: 345px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="card">
   <div class="front" onclick="getCard(0)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
   <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <div class="front" onclick="getCard(1)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
   <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <div class="front" onclick="getCard(2)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
   <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg3"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the link on working [pen](https://codepen.io/MegaZef/pen/JqXyOO) when you are clicking on the card it reverse and random picture is shown, but in safari and ios it shows card back after clicking on card and reversing. Any help and tips would be appreciated.

Comment: It works for me in safari 12.x . Are you sure did you check local browser cache! Looks like taror. After click card must be visible ?

Comment: I checked cache, it still diesn't work

Comment: yes, after you are clicking on card it reverses, and another image is shown, card is still visible after reversing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simple add annotation for web-kit transform just like you already do with "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden".

Chrome is most optimised browser. Safari and chrome share web-kit implementation but chrome looks like reading minds. For safari you must use web-kit prefix for chrome no need.

Try this :

```js
  var images = [];

  (function() {
    generateCards()
  })();

  var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

  Array.from(cards).forEach(function(card) {
    card.addEventListener('click', function() {
      Array.from(card.querySelectorAll('.back, .front')).forEach(function(el) {
        ['back', 'front'].forEach(function(s) {
          el.classList.toggle(s)
        });
      });
    });
  });

  //Displaying different images on click
  function cardImg(index) {
    var cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,10);
    if (images[index] !== undefined) 
    {
      images[index] = -1;
    }

    while (images.indexOf(cardNewImg)!= -1){
      cardNewImg = randomIntFromInterval(2,11); 
    }  
    images[index] = cardNewImg;
  }

  function generateCards() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      cardImg(i);
    }
  }

  function getCard(index) {
    if(!images[index].valid) {
      cardImg(index)
    }
    document["randimg"+(index + 1)].src = "https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/" + images[index]+".jpg";
  }

  function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
  {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
  }
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
 display: none;
}

.wrap {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #A770EF;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #FDB99B, #CF8BF3, #A770EF);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FDB99B, #CF8BF3, #A770EF); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.card {
 width: 200px;
 height: 345px;
 position: relative;
 perspective: 1000px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 50px;
}

.front, .back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 transition: 1s;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.front {
 transform: rotateY(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
}

.back  {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.img1 {
 width: 200px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 height: 345px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front" onclick="getCard(0)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front" onclick="getCard(1)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="front" onclick="getCard(2)"><img class="img1" src="https://lp.rustaro.ru/wp-content/uploads/transformation/cards/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back"><img class="img1" src="" name="randimg3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```